# Why is .vimrc not changing the appearance of vimtutor?

Tags: vim

I am starting with Vim.

I created a `~/.vimrc` file in my home directory and started adding preferences.

When I save and start the file again I can see the preferences taking effect in my `vim`. However, when I reopen my `vimtutor` I can't see the preferences I made.

I also created another text file in a different folder to see that my preferences are working and they are. So why aren't they being used by my vimtutor file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man vimtutor`:

```
Vim is always started in Vi compatible mode.
```

From `man vim`:

```
-C    Compatible.  Set the 'compatible' option.  This will make Vim behave mostly like Vi, even though a .vimrc file exists.
```

So when you start `vimtutor`, it starts in compatible mode, which ignores your vimrc file.

The meat of `vimtutor` is really just a text file, though.  Nothing special about it, other than the fact that (a) it makes a copy of the tutor file so it can be modified without changing the original file, and (b) it always starts in vi compatible mode.

If you want to open the tutor text file (a copy of it) using your vimrc settings instead of with vi compatible mode, run `vimtutor`, then type `:w myvimtutorfile` to save the text file in your current directory.  Next, enter `:q!` to exit vimtutor, and then at the command line enter `vim myvimtutorfile`, and you should see your .vimrc settings take effect.

Comment: @BJR: I'm a big `vi` fan, so although it has nothing to do with your question, I wanted to share my two favorite resources related to vi/vim:  http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html is a great introduction to the power of vi, and https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~kuperman/help/vim/help.html explains how to navigate the built-in help (CRUCIAL to know this to teach yourself advanced features!)  But definitely start by completing the entire tutorial in `vimtutor`.  Enjoy!  :)